# I can't edit the Access tag wiki

Tags: support, tag-wiki

At least once or twice a day someone asks a question about Microsoft Access using the access tag.  However the much more accepted tag is ms-access.    I've edited the ms-access wiki tag as I have sufficient repuation, etc.   I also look for access tags and, if appropriate, retag with the ms-access tag.

However I'd like to adit the access tag wiki to tell folks who are asking Microsoft Access questions to use the ms-access tag as they will likely get an answer much quicker.  But I can't because I don't have enough of an access tag repuatation, etc.

(Of course I do get some points because there are frequently unanswered questions using the access tag so I really shouldn't even be complaining.)

So can someone who is a moderator or whatever update the access tag wiki?

Answer (score -1):

What should be done is a synonym. There is already one proposed, you can vote for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/synonyms). Once it is accepted, it will automatically convert `access` tag to `ms-access`.

Comment: Most of the questions currently tagged `[access]` have however to get rid of the tag then since they don't cover MS Access at all.

Comment: For whatever reason though folks are using the access tag for other purposes so I disagree with this idea.

Comment: @Tony the other use of the tag access are rather vague and I'm not entirely sure they are appropriate. "How do I access the property x within a language ?". It's mostly question that are asked this way that are tagged [access].

Comment: Yes, I do agree that many users of the access tag are vague and likely not appropriate.  But I'm also not going to muck with someone's tags without good reason.